# Why is an exception generated in java when I use the following code

Tags: java, jsoup

```
    Document doc1;
    String url="http://www.google.com";
    url= url +" and 1=1";
    doc1=Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

Here there is no problem with the connection as the following code gives no exception. The exception is generated only when I try to get the HTML code with the above code.

```
    Document doc1;
    String url="http://www.google.com";
    url= url +" and 1=1";
    Jsoup.connect(url);
```

Thanks!

Comment: What exception? Show us the full stack trace.

Comment: Are you trying to do some sort of injection attack?

Comment: probably because the URL is not validated until `get()`

Comment: @user2357112 Yes I am trying to do a injection attack.

Comment: @RC:I am sorry but I am not getting you. How can the URL be not validated when it is able to connect properly in the code given below?

Comment: @Malav in the second code sample, there's no `get()`

Answer (score 0):

`JSoup.connect` doesn't actually try to connect to the website. If you look through the [documentation](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#connect%28java.lang.String%29), you'll see that it only creates a Connection object. You can chain method calls on the Connection to set cookies, user agent, and other stuff before calling `get`, `execute`, `post`, or one of the other methods that will actually send the request.

([Here's another documentation link that might be easier to browse.](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/) Unfortunately, Javadoc's use of frames makes linking awkward.)

Answer (score 0):

According to Jsoup javadoc:

[`Jsoup.connect(String url)`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#connect%28java.lang.String%29):

> Creates a new Connection to a URL. Use to fetch and parse a HTML page.

[`Connection.get()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#get%28%29):

> Execute the request as a GET, and parse the result.

So in the first sample you are querying google and getting an `IOException` because of the invalid URL but not in the second sample (no query is made)

Answer (score 0):

`Jsoup.connect` doesn't actually connect to anything. It just creates a `Connection` object. If you want to set any special properties of the connection, you can do it before you call `get()` which is what actually connects.

As for why you get an exception: probably because `http://www.google.com and 1=1` is not a valid URL.

Comment: @Malav I have no idea what you are trying to say. Please elaborate.

Comment: 'http://www.google.com and 1=1'. When I give this URL to browser it does give a webpage. So should I get a parsed HTML code when I chain 'get()' method to 'Jsoup.connect()' ?